# 10!=2 is getting true and "Hello "+10!=2 compilation error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I am preparing for Oracle certification exam so could you explain how 10!=2 is getting true and  compilation error, I have mention a small program below.
10!=2 : why it is true
"Hello "+10!=2 : why it is compile time error

public class Demo1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args1) {   
    System.out.println(10!=2);  //Output is True
    System.out.println("Hello "+10!=2); //Compile Time Error
}
```

}

Comment: in the second statement, you are doing "Hello 10" != 2, because of String concatenation. Try "Hello " + (10 != 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check basics of java and generally programming. '==' sign checks if values are the same, '!=' checks if values are not the same.
So 10!=2 means is 10 different than 2, and you get 'true'.

Comment: oh I thought it is factorial something, got it thanks a lot

Comment: '=!' and '!=' are not the same.  Also, you obviously didn't read the question. Your answer doesn't explain why there is a compile time error

Comment: now it is clear, thanks

Comment: Also: '==' checks if  values are the same: NO. it doesn't. It checks whether or not the reference is the same. For primitive types, there are no duplicates, that's why for primitives you can check it to compare the values. That's a different matter

Comment: That's why I said to check basics of Java and programming.

Answer (score 1):

for concat boolean with string in java you first need to store answer in a variable.
try using this.

```
public static void main(String[] args1) {
    boolean a=10!=2;
    System.out.println(a);  //Output is True
    System.out.println("Hello "+a);// Output is Hello true
}
```

Comment: why would this be needed? putting ( ) around the 10 != 2 changes the order of execution, and gives the correct result as well. Basically, what you are doing is creating an additional (not needed) variable. Not an efficient way to approach the issue.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, ```System.out.println("Hello "+(10!=2)) sh``` should be the accepted answer here.
```Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'int'```

Comment: This is a good solution as well